# How to get Public DNS for Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to read/write data from Bigtable using Spark Job in google shell.

I have used the API provided by Google cloud for bigtable connection - https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-java-hello

What i am looking for is to use spark internal functions to connect to bigtable but i am not sure of the IP Address/ Public DNS of the Bigtable instance.

In AWS i have used the function :- getEMRMasterPublicDNS

Not sure if google cloud provides something similar to this or not.

Please suggest any workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

bigtable.googleapis.com:443 is the endpoint for Bigtable data operations, and bigtableadmin.googleapis.com:443 for admin operations.

Programmatically from the java client I think it would be something like:

```
new BigtableOptions.Builder().build().getDataHost() // or getPort()
```